# Read PrivateKey from WAS KeyStore

Tags: certificate, websphere, websphere-8, pki

We are using WAS 8.5 and our certificate is stored in NodeDefaultKeyStore (Type: PCKS12).

Is it possible to read PrivateKey from this type of key store in webservice application? Any hint how to connect to WAS key store?

Answer (score 3):

First, you will need the password for the key.  Next, you may need to figure out the management scope of the keystore.  For instance:

(cell):myCell:(node):myNode

The replacements are myCell and myNode.  Sometimes you can get away without using the management scope and sometimes you can't.  Try calling getJavaKeyStore with null for the management scope to see if it works for you.  If not, then you'll have to define the management scope.

```
import com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.KeyStoreManager;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Key;
...
String mgmtScopeString="(cell):"+myCell+":(node):"+myNode;
KeyStore keystore = 
    KeyStoreManager.getInstance().getJavaKeyStore("NodeDefaultKeyStore", 
    mgmtScopeString);        
Key myKey = keystore.getKey(alias,password.toCharArray());
```